# Finding population standard deviation without sample size

Tags: statistics

> Annual starting salaries for college graduates with degrees in business administration are generally expected to be between $30,000 and $45,000. Assume that a 95% confidence interval estimate of the population mean annual starting salary is desired.
>
> What is the planning value for the population standard deviation (to the nearest whole number)?

I know that the Margin of Error is 7500. I know that this can be found using the formula $z_{a/2}*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $. After his I am stuck because I don't know the sample population.